# Crawling log - Unable to connect to Solr

Tags: solr

Solr is accessible with https but not with http in my local.

What could be the reason ? Am i missing some configuration ?

```
ManagedPoolThread #1 11:53:35 WARN  Unable to connect to Solr: [http://localhost:8983/solr], the [SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException] was caught.
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine
Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrCoreAdmin.Status()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrStatus.OkSolrStatus()
```

#### EDIT: Added updates from comments:

I verified following things-

1. Below configs are enabled-

   ```
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Core
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web
   ```
2. checked solr logs -- no errors.
3. checked crawling logs - found error Unable to connect to Solr: [http://localhost:8983/solr]
4. tried to access solr url over http its not accessible (localhost refused to connect.), however its accessible over https
5. solr service is up.

Comment: Probably. We would need to see a lot of your configs to know. Did you check the basics? what have you investigated? did you read https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1245/unable-to-connect-to-http-localhost8983-solr-core-mycore?rq=1 ?

Comment: I verified following things-
1. Below configs are enabled-    
 Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Core
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web


2. checked solr logs -- no errors.
3. checked crawling logs - found error Unable to connect to Solr: [http://localhost:8983/solr]
4. tried to access solr url over http its not accessible (localhost refused to connect.), however its accessible over https
5. solr service is up.

Comment: why do you need it to run on http, we only need it on https. Is there a case where you need it?

Comment: Using  Sitecore. 8.2 (rev. 171121) - There is one instance where already its working on http so was thinking if this could be reason.

Comment: This particular Solr version is tricky, sometimes you have to stop Solr entirely, then stop Sitecore entirely and start Solr, and then Sitecore (https://viniciusdeschamps.com.br/sitecore-solr-is-not-starting-tricky-2/). Give a shot and let us know

Answer (score 2):

Go to config **Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config (\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentSearch)** and search for **ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress** setting and make it **https://localhost:8983/solr**

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" value= "https://localhost:8983/solr" />
```

Comment: Unable to connect to Solr: [https://localhost:8983/solr], the [SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException] was caught.
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Get(String relativeUrl, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrCoreAdmin.Status()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider
Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: @siddharth this case a problem that the certificate is not trusted. Add the certificate to the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". Here you can find info how to do it: https://success.outsystems.com/Support/Enterprise_Customers/Installation/Add_self_signed_certificate_to_trusted_root_store_on_OutSystems

Comment: Thanks all. Instead of using solr as http, i followed below link and generated local ssl certificate for Solr. Now indexes are appearing.
 https://gist.github.com/kamsar/c3c8322c1ec40eac64c7dd546e5124de

Comment: @siddharth I don't understand how generating new cert worked.. Error message is showing that it's trying to connect over HTTP and not HTTPS. This solution can work when request was made to HTTPS and cert was not intalled in Trusted Root Cert Authority.

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not support both HTTP and HTTPS at the same. You can only use one of them at a time.

So, make sure to update your config files(e.g. `\App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config`) to use only `https://localhost:8983/solr`.

Comment: configured as -
<setting name="ContentSearch.Provider" value="Solr"/>
<setting name="ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" value= "http://localhost:8983/solr" />

Comment: make this entry as https://localhost:8983/solr and then check

Comment: ERROR Unable to connect to [https://localhost:8983/solr], Core: [social_messages_web]
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Comment: Aha okay, I was under impression that you are using Sitecore 9.

Answer (score 0):

My old instance was using Solr-5.5.1, I was able to connect using http://localhost:8983/solr. However, for my new instance , solr-6.6.2 is installed and I could not connect to it over http.

I followed the below URL to generate a local SSL certificate for solr -
https://gist.github.com/kamsar/c3c8322c1ec40eac64c7dd546e5124de.

Things to be taken care of while following the above URL-

1. Add the path of the Keystore to the environment variable. Added "`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_261\bin`" to the Path variable.
2. Check and confirm the path of **solr-ssl.keystore.jks** file in your machine -

```
 .\solrssl.ps1 -keystoreFile
    C:\solr\solr-6.6.2\server\etc\solr-ssl.keystore.jks
```

Still, solr is not accessible with http://localhost:8983/solr, however after certification installation and using https://localhost:8983/solr , the indexing manager starts showing indexes.